# Is there any way to read GraphQL Directives on a Type with Query Introspection?

Tags: graphql, introspection

For use cases like authentication it may be of use to add custom directives to a GraphQL schema as shown in the documentation: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v16/sdl-directives

For example the Employee type has a salary field that had a directive on it meaning that only the manager role is allowed to read it:

```graphql
directive @auth(role: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

type Employee {
  id: ID
  name: String!
  startDate: String!
  salary: Float @auth(role: "manager")
}
```

From the client side I would like to be able to read these directives on the Employee type using an Introspection query.

Is that possible at all? Would you be able provide a sample query for the example above?

Comment: why? more specific use case? ... you can check user roles/capabilities and use `@include` 'client' directive to conditionally query for this field (hide nulled/undefined on FE) ... or simply use other set of queries for different caps ... UI should know caps before this kind of query not using introspection ... sure, this would be helpful but not ATM

Comment: Why: it would be useful for introspection to generate docs based on the directives applied to a type or query.

Answer (score 7):

This is not currently supported by GraphQL. You can use introspection to find out what directives exist in the schema, but you cannot use it to find out which fields had directives applied to them. You can see additional discussion around this issue [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/300).