# Iterate Over Custom Directives in GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

I have a simplified schema.graphql file with one type and one custom directive (at the field and object level). In Typescript, how can I programmatically get the type and type directive, and iterate over the fields and field directives?

```
type Test @myCustomDirective() {
  id: String! @myCustomDirective()
}
```

This post says "This is not currently supported by GraphQL":
[Is there any way to read GraphQL Directives on a Type with Query Introspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064766/is-there-any-way-to-read-graphql-directives-on-a-type-with-query-introspection?rq=1)

And the GitHub issue says this feature is being considered:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/300

Then how is AWS AppSync doing this? See below.

```
// The following keeps custom directives:
parse(schema); // Return type: graphql.DocumentNode

// The following removes custom directives:
buildSchema(schema); // Return type: GraphQLSchema
```

1. AWS AppSync > Export Schema > Schema.json does include custom directives but is an AWS AppSync specific solution and is an expensive API operation.

```
aws appsync get-introspection-schema --api-id abc123 --format JSON --include-directives output.json
```

2. I tried GraphQL Code Generator Introspection plugin. But it removes custom directives from types and fields.

   https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/introspection
3. I tried graphql/utilities but it also removes custom directives from types and fields.

```
graphql.introspectionFromSchema(graphqlSchema)

// or

graphql.graphqlSync({ schema: graphqlSchema, source: graphql.getIntrospectionQuery() }).data as unknown as graphql.IntrospectionQuery;
```

https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "GraphQL Tools" approach creates an iteratable schema but may not be the most efficient approach:

"The graphql-tools package allows you to create a GraphQL.js GraphQLSchema instance from GraphQL schema language using the function makeExecutableSchema"
https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/generate-schema

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';


const schemaFile = await fs.readFile(
    './schema.graphql'
);

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: gql(schemaFile.toString())
});``

const output = executableSchema.getType('Test');


// output.astNode.directives sample output:

{
    kind: 'Directive',
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'myCustomDirective1' },
    arguments: [ [Object] ]
},
{
    kind: 'Directive',
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'myCustomDirective' },
    arguments: [ [Object] ]
}

// output.astNode['fields'] sample output:

[{
    kind: 'FieldDefinition',
    description: undefined,
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'id' },       
    arguments: [],
    type: { kind: 'NamedType', name: [Object] },  
    directives: [ [Object] ]
}]
```